# Not able to move a google maps map using move_to_element_with_offset() in selenium

Tags: python, google-maps, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to open google maps in selenium webdriver using python and drag the map around but my current solution doesnt drag the map.

My code opens a map in google maps using selenium Webdriver. I am attempting to drag this map by using `.click_and_hold()` followed  by `.move_to_element_with_offset`.

This is my code block for this part.

```
map = driver.find_element(By.ID, "app-container")
ActionChains(driver)\
    .click_and_hold(map)\
    .move_to_element_with_offset(map, 500, 500)\
    .perform()
```

I am taking a screenshot before and after this block to see if it works but sadly it doesnt seem to do so. I can see that the screen is being clicked because a pop-up on the top left of the screen disappears which does not happen if i remove this part of the code.

Comment: My thoughts here is that the `move_to_element_with_offset` works by "moving into" the element, and not within. Google Maps dragging works if you drag and hold **within** the map.